# Observable.from() in angular 2 tests - errors inside test method

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs5

I have to use an Observable in my tests and this little code:

```
it("should emit values", () => {
   const f = Observable.of([1, 3, 5]);
   f.subscribe(d => console.log(d));
});
```

gives the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Observable_1.Observable.of([1, 3, 5])')

**But** if I put these 2 lines of code **inside a component** (say, in ngOnInit) I see emitted values and **no error**. I wonder if this me or angular 2 has some issues with its testing codebase?

Just in case, these are all imports I use in this particular test file:

---

```
import {
it,
inject,
injectAsync,
beforeEachProviders,
TestComponentBuilder
} from 'angular2/testing';

import {ComponentFixture, dispatchEvent, fakeAsync, tick} from 'angular2/testing_internal';

import {provide, bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {FormBuilder} from 'angular2/common';
import {By} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {ArrayObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/fromArray';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/subject/BehaviorSubject';

import {SpyLocation} from 'angular2/src/mock/location_mock';
import {RootRouter} from 'angular2/src/router/router';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouteParams, ComponentInstruction, RouteData, Location, ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT} from 'angular2/router';
import {
RouteConfig,
Route,
AuxRoute,
AsyncRoute,
Redirect
} from 'angular2/src/router/route_config_decorator';
import {RouteRegistry} from 'angular2/src/router/route_registry';
import {DirectiveResolver} from 'angular2/src/core/linker/directive_resolver';
import {ResolvedInstruction} from 'angular2/src/router/instruction';
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';` to `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';` ? It might help because importing it this way will get you all the operations which you might use in your component.